# Datatables cant get response

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

Im trying to show university schedule with datatables . Im sending request with datatable ajax . But as response get undefined .

server side code : I have array with schedule.

```
<?php
// File: schedule_ajax_return.php
$data = [
  1 => [
    "monday" => "Ағылшын тілі 1год группа 8К</br>Қонысбаева Айжан Әміржанқызы</br>203",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  2 => [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  3 => [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  4 => [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  5 => [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then Im returning it as json with `echo json_encode($array);`

client side Im accepting response and showing data in colums with columns

```
var table = $('#schedule_by_group').DataTable({
    select:true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    ajax: {
        "url": "schedule_ajax_return.php",
        "dataSrc": "",
        "data":{"group_id": group_id},
        "type": "POST"
    },
    columns : [
        {"data": "monday"},
        {"data": "tuesday"},
        {"data": "wednesday"},
        {"data": "thursday"},
        {"data": "friday"}
    ]
});
```

In documentation  of datatables I read that I can send data as array of arrays or array of objects . So Im sending It as array of arrays but It shows undefined.

Comment: Why do you have `"dataSrc": "",`? Also is the data you're trying to get using ajax inside a json file called `package.json`? Is it the right path? I think you're just having a hard time understanding how their ajax works. Please read [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) thoroughly.

Comment: @Islam Elshobokshy  I just used package.json as test . actually path is schedule_ajax_return.php . I forget here to change it . I read in docementation that "dataSrc": "", is must have thing .

Comment: What format are you delivering the content from the server to the browser? JSON?

Comment: @yunzen Yeah . Im converting two dimensional array to json and sending it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this documentation about [Data aaray location](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location) on [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

Emphasis mine:

> 1) Simple array of data:
>
> > `// ...
> >     dataSrc: ''
> >     // ...`
>
> 2) Object with data property - note that the data parameter format shown here can be used with a simplified DataTables initialisation as **data is the default property** that DataTables looks for in the source data object.
>
> > `// ...
> >     dataSrc: 'data'
> >     // ...`

Your JSON response should be

```
[
  {
    "monday": "Ағылшын тілі 1год группа 8К</br>Қонысбаева Айжан Әміржанқызы</br>203",
    "tuesday": "</br></br>",
    "wednesday": "</br></br>",
    "thursday": "</br></br>",
    "friday": "</br></br>"
  },
  {
    "monday": "</br><br>",
    "tuesday": "</br></br>",
    "wednesday": "</br></br>",
    "thursday": "</br></br>",
    "friday": "</br></br>"
  },
  {
    "monday": "</br><br>",
    "tuesday": "</br></br>",
    "wednesday": "</br></br>",
    "thursday": "</br></br>",
    "friday": "</br></br>"
  },
  {
    "monday": "</br><br>",
    "tuesday": "</br></br>",
    "wednesday": "</br></br>",
    "thursday": "</br></br>",
    "friday": "</br></br>"
  },
  {
    "monday": "</br><br>",
    "tuesday": "</br></br>",
    "wednesday": "</br></br>",
    "thursday": "</br></br>",
    "friday": "</br></br>"
  }
]
```

to work with `dataSrc: "",`
[[Explore online on jsoneditoronline.org](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=fa00185eda5f43499b1eb581212ae460)]

If your JSON has this structure

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "monday": "Ағылшын тілі 1год группа 8К</br>Қонысбаева Айжан Әміржанқызы</br>203",
      "tuesday": "</br></br>",
      "wednesday": "W</br></br>",
      "thursday": "</br></br>",
      "friday": "</br></br>"
    },
    {
      "monday": "</br><br>",
      "tuesday": "</br></br>",
      "wednesday": "</br></br>",
      "thursday": "</br></br>",
      "friday": "</br></br>"
    },
    {
      "monday": "</br><br>",
      "tuesday": "</br></br>",
      "wednesday": "W2</br></br>",
      "thursday": "</br></br>",
      "friday": "</br></br>"
    },
    {
      "monday": "</br><br>",
      "tuesday": "</br></br>",
      "wednesday": "</br></br>",
      "thursday": "</br></br>",
      "friday": "</br></br>"
    },
    {
      "monday": "</br><br>",
      "tuesday": "</br></br>",
      "wednesday": "</br></br>",
      "thursday": "</br></br>",
      "friday": "</br></br>"
    }
  ]
}
```

you can omit the `dataSrc: "",` as the default value of `"data"` would be used.
[[Explore online on jsoneditoronline.org](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4e6dceda07c3418fb189c187071add52)]

I've made an [example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xowjrvyn9p) that uses static JSON instead of an PHP array, but the principle should be clear. I made two JSON file (`test-array.json` and `test-data.json`). `test-array.json` works with `dataSrc: ""` or `dataSrc: null`; and `test-data.json` works with `dataSrc: "data"` or `dataSrc: undefined`.

But your PHP code creates a different structure as seen [here in 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LcRlq) ([structure inspect](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=954bdac6ca424d4db39acd2c6cc7f523)). The PHP code `[ 1 => [ '...' ] ]` creates an associative array, not an indexed array. Associative Arrays are json_encoded to JSON objects, not JSON arrays as we would need. To achieve this, you must omit the keys (though they are numeric) in your array. This should do:

```
<?php
// File: schedule_ajax_return.php
$data = [
  [
    "monday" => "Ағылшын тілі 1год группа 8К</br>Қонысбаева Айжан Әміржанқызы</br>203",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
  [
    "monday" => "</br><br>",
    "tuesday" => "</br></br>",
    "wednesday" => "</br></br>",
    "thursday" => "</br></br>",
    "friday" => "</br></br>",
  ],
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

See [here on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Rck7V)